# Ubuntu command to change IP address only works for about half a minute before changing back

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip

According to https://www.howtogeek.com/118337/stupid-geek-tricks-change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-line-in-linux/
and [Change IP address permanently with ifconfig in Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/564797/change-ip-address-permanently-with-ifconfig-in-debian)
the command
ifconfig eth0 169.254.1.99 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
should change the ip configuration until the machine is rebooted. 
In my case it lasts about 30-40 seconds (until a device on this network stops pinging and "network disconnected" message pops up) then changes back to DHCP mode. The command "dhclient eth0 -v" (to change to DHCP) works fine so it probably just wants to automatically change back to DHCP for some reason. 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: (32 bit version)

Comment: do you need dhcp? if not you could just disable it

Answer (score -1):

Disable Network Manager

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```